# Playwright - Parameterize projects with fixture and pom

Tags: playwright

I'm trying to figure out what the best way is to parameterize a project with fixture and pom. I'm thinking that it would be nice to have a project use option, similar like setting the browser or device type for example.

I'm thinking that by setting the appConfig, I will be able to conditionally pass which POM and Fixture to use.

```js
// playwright.config.ts

Projects: [
  {
    name: 'App 1',
    use: { appConfig: 1 }
  },
  {
    name: 'App 2',
    use: { appConfig: 2 }
  }
]


// some-test.spec.ts

  test('Test to be run for each project', async ({ page, appConfig }) => {
    await page.goto(); //goes to correct url
    await page.login(appConfig.credentials); //logs in with the correct credentials
  });
```

I haven't really found any example online for achieving this. The idea of using that appConfig, us so that I can have the same code for the tests/steps, thanks to the POM, and that the test will use the unique data, thanks to the fixture.

Comment: You define different projects to execute under either different configurations or for different browsers/devices but not different configurations under a single project per playwright docs.

Comment: Why would you parameterize a project with "fixture and pom" anyways ? What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Can you explain with an use case example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured out how to achieve this. Unsure how useful it is, but maybe it is of help or inspiration for someone else.

```js
// custom-test.ts

import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
// App 1
import { AppOneData } from './app-one-data';
import { AppOnePOMv1 } from './app-one-pom-1';
import { AppOnePOMv2 } from './app-one-pom-2';
// App 2
import { AppTwoData } from './app-two-data';
import { AppTwoPOMv1 } from './app-two-pom-1';
import { AppTwoPOMv2 } from './app-one-pom-2';

// Types
type SysConfigNames =  'AppOne' | 'AppTwo'
type Systems = Record<SysConfigNames, SysConfigSettings>;
type SysConfigSettings = {
  data: MyData;
  pageObjects: MyPageObjects;
}
type MyData = { items: { fruit: string; veggie: string } };
type MyPageObjects = { poms: { v1: any; v2: any }};
type CustomFixtures = {
  items: MyData['items'];
  poms: MyPageObjects['poms']
}

// New "testOption" 
export type CustomTestOptions = {
  sysConfig: SysConfigNames;
};

// System Configs
const systems: Systems = {
  AppOne: { data: AppOneData, pageObjects: { poms: { v1: AppOnePOMv1, v2: AppOnePOMv2} } },
  AppTwo: { data: AppTwoData, pageObjects: { poms: { v1: AppTwoPOMv1, v2: AppTwoPOMv2} }},
};

const defaultValue: SysConfigNames = "AppOne";

// Custom Test w Fixtures
export const test = base.extend<CustomTestOptions & CustomFixtures>({
  sysConfig: [defaultValue, { option: true }],
  items: async ({ sysConfig }, use) => {
    const value = systems[sysConfig].data.items;
    await use(value);
  },
  poms: async ({ sysConfig }, use) => {
    const value = systems[sysConfig].pageObjects.poms;
    await use(value);
  },
});
```

```js
// playwright.config.ts

import { PlaywrightTestConfig } from "@playwright/test";
import { CustomTestOptions } from './custom-test';

const config: PlaywrightTestConfig<CustomTestOptions> = {
  projects: [
    {
      name: "Application One",
      testDir: "./tests/",
      use: { sysConfig: 'AppOne'},
    },
    {
      name: "Application Two",
      testDir: "./tests/",
      use: { sysConfig: 'AppTwo'},
    }
  ]
};
export default config;
```

```js
// test.spec.ts

import { test } from './custom-test';

test('test', async ({ page, items, poms }) => {
    const myPage = new poms.v1(page);
    await myPage.goto();
    await myPage.purchase(items.fruit)
});
```